# attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation method not working in ios 8

Tags: ipad, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation

I know iOS 8 has lots of updates. I have done an fix in my app for iOS 7 and below to force rotate my app orientation when it needs using `[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation] method. But unfortunately it's not working in iOS 8(its not calling the shouldAutorotate method further). Any one please suggest alternate solution or better iOS 8 fix for this problem.

Comment: Got any solution for this ??

Comment: In my case, I have presented a screen modally over an base viewcontorller. On dismiss, I have used the "attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation" on my base viewcontroller but it doesn't work on ios 8. So instead of presenting modally, I have subviewed the viewcontroller with custom modal animation. This is how i fixed in my case... @Arun_k

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you are trying to rotate viewController to the orientation in the setting, `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` doesn't work. Not sure why but that is what I figured out so far.